# Interaction between arrays (new to Java)

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a little game (rock, paper, scissors) in JFrame and it's working fine!

Only problem is that I can't get the text and buttons on my welcome screen to "line up" in the way I want it to.

I've made two arrays of the JLabels and the Font and i have no idea on how to make them... notice eatchother.

```
JLabel [] labels = {(new JLabel("*****VÄLKOMMEN TILL MITT SPEL!*****")),new JLabel("Reglerna är enkla: "),new JLabel(" Du tävlar mot datorn i helt vanlig sten, sax, påse."),new JLabel("Du väljer ett drag med hjälp av knapparna."),new JLabel("Datorn slumpgenererar mellan de tre alternativen."),new JLabel("Först till den angivna poängen vinner!"),new JLabel("REDO ATT STARTA?")};

Font [] Typsnitt = {(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 60))};
```

I have a pic but for are unable to upload it for "reputation reasons"

Here's all the code for the welcome window.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class SimpeltSpel extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   SimpeltSpel ny = new SimpeltSpel();
   ny.setVisible(true);

  }
   public JButton JaKnapp;
   public JButton NejKnapp;
   public JButton Sten;
   public JButton Sax;
   public JButton Påse;
   {
    JaKnapp = new JButton();
    JaKnapp.setText("     Ja     ");

    NejKnapp = new JButton();
    NejKnapp.setText("     Nej     ");
   }

 public SimpeltSpel() {
  super("Sten,Sax,Påse!");
  this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
  this.setResizable(false);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel [] labels = {(new JLabel("*****VÄLKOMMEN TILL MITT SPEL!*****")),new JLabel("Reglerna är enkla: "),new JLabel(" Du tävlar mot datorn i helt vanlig sten, sax, påse."),new JLabel("Du väljer ett drag med hjälp av knapparna."),new JLabel("Datorn slumpgenererar mellan de tre alternativen."),new JLabel("Först till den angivna poängen vinner!"),new JLabel("REDO ATT STARTA?")};
    Font [] Typsnitt = {(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15)),(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 60))};

     labels[0].setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

     for (int i = 0; i<7; i++){
         getContentPane().add(labels[i]);
     }
     add(JaKnapp);
     add(NejKnapp);

     setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
     setVisible(true);
     Knappar behandlare = new Knappar();
     JaKnapp.addActionListener(behandlare);
     NejKnapp.addActionListener(behandlare);

 }
 private class Knappar implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
   Object KnappTryck = event.getSource();
      if (KnappTryck == NejKnapp){
       System.exit(0);
      }
      else if (KnappTryck == JaKnapp) {

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the array of fonts. What do you want to do? Assign a font to each label?

Comment: You should follow the Java conventions and name your variables with lower case first letter (in english, inte på svenska ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want your layout to look like a grid use [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) with 2 columns. Set it like this before adding any components:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

From the API docs for [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/):

> The GridLayout class is a layout manager that lays out a container's
>   components in a rectangular grid.

---

Note that you are today using [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) which lays out the components in a directional flow, quoted from the API:

> A flow layout arranges components in a directional flow, much like
>   lines of text in a paragraph. The flow direction is determined by the
>   container's componentOrientation property and may be one of two
>   values: